# Why is {key : "value"} different from {"key" : "value"}?

Tags: javascript, object

Directly from the node REPL:

```
> d1 = {key : "value"}
{ key: 'value' }
> d2 = {"key" : "value"}
{ key: 'value' }
> d1 == d2
false
```

Why is d1 different from d2 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't, you'd get the same result if you just repeated the first line with `d2` instead of `d1`. However, the two objects you're creating are *different* objects, and so they are not `==`. `==` with object references checks to see if the two operands refer to the same object ([Section 11.9.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) of the spec). What you have there is two objects which both have a property called `key` with the value "value".

Comment: @João Pinto Jerónimo but strings are treated specially in comparisons using the "==" and "!=" operators - ordinary objects are different.

Comment: @Pointy: Well, most strings are primitives, but you're quite correct that even `String` instances are handled differently from other objects. So are `Number` instances. @João - Be sure to read the linked details.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are two different objects. It's not comparing the members of the object.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same object. You're doing a reference equality comparison, not a value comparison.

Comment: How do I make a value comparison ?

Comment: @João: For general-purpose objects, there's nothing built-in. You have to roll your own function. I think most people tend to call that function `equals`, e.g. `d1.equals(d2)`, a name that comes from the otherwise largely-unrelated Java programming language.